# Infinite loading screen in Watch Dogs

Tags: watch-dogs

It loads to about 80% on the bar, but not further. Wondering if anyone else have had the same problem.
If you have experienced the same thing PLEASE let me know if you have a fix for it.

The crash is just that it stops working, tho it takes some time for it to crash.
Not very keen on starting a new game file.

Don't know if it makes any difference, but i just finished act 1 and bought the Ghost vehicle on Uplay store right after saving the game.

Comment: It sounds like your save file might be corrupted.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xuYIPRhHfcM
I found this video. It seems like others have had the same problem.

You say that the file might be corrupted, is there anything i can do about that?

Comment: I don't know.  That would require knowing how Watch Dogs formats its save files, and I don't even play the game.  It's just in my experience, when a save can't be loaded, it's probably corrupted.

Comment: I didn't find the solution, so i started a new gamefile. It works now. I just hope they fix the issue so it doesn't happen again!

Thanks alot for the answers MBraedley! You should try the game, it's fun ;) Take care!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is happening to [a lot](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/704529-watch-dogs/69319626) [of other](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/704529-watch-dogs/69331806) [people](http://www.giantbomb.com/watch-dogs/3030-38538/forums/cant-get-past-the-first-load-screen-1484712/), across [all platforms](http://forums.ubi.com/showthread.php/885291-Watch-Dogs-Infinite-Loading-Screen-on-Start-Up?p=10003106).  The official Ubisoft forums have a [150-page thread](http://forums.ubi.com/showthread.php/882580-OFFICIAL-Game-stuck-on-loading-screen) on the issue.

So, Ubisoft is aware of the issue, and is *(presumably)* working on a fix.

[Edit] [The latest word from the Ubisoft staff](http://forums.ubi.com/showthread.php/882580-OFFICIAL-Game-stuck-on-loading-screen?s=3d9a055788fd0fe8e9fb3620aad9dad2&p=10008145&viewfull=1#post10008145):

> *(June 1st 2014)*
>   The team are working on the issue, is the best I can say at the moment.

---

It appears to happen when you unlock in-game items from the Ubisoft store.  Unfortunately, **there is currently no known workaround.**  You'll either have to start a new game, or wait for Ubisoft to provide a fix.

And in the meanwhile, **don't purchase any in-game items from the Ubisoft store!**

Answer (score 2):

[This solution on the Ubisoft Forums](http://forums.ubi.com/showthread.php/884314-Save-file-corrupted-Watch-Dogs-stuck-in-loading-screen?s=df956594115cc261c718a2a6ae7a431d&p=10003151&viewfull=1#post10003151) did the trick for me.

Navigate to the savegame folder, which for me was `C:\Program Files (x86)\Ubisoft\Ubisoft Game Launcher\savegames\67926a76-de90-4889-8cab-918ac6b11664\274`

You will find 4 files in here back them up and put just 1.save back in. Start Watch Dogs and load your save it should work (did for me).

Make sure you make a backup of the 4 files first.

Comment: Nice, thanks for posting!  Make sure to also read [this comment](http://forums.ubi.com/showthread.php/884314-Save-file-corrupted-Watch-Dogs-stuck-in-loading-screen?p=10003994&viewfull=1#post10003994) from that thread.

Answer (score 0):

okey if you want your old saves back there is a way, there are 2 places where the saves exist, one is in Program Files (x86) -> Ubisoft -> Ubisoft Game Luncher -> 0 inside 4 files. the second bunch is in the original game folder under Bin -> also 4 files. its simple, copy the 4 files from the Ubisoft folder into an empty folder. now start watch dogs and play a new game if you haven't already, play until the game performs a save and then just exit, now copy over the save that you took from the Ubisoft folder Over the files in the Bin folder. good luck.﻿

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem too on PC. Your save file is corrupted. Delete your save files and done. Start a new game and its good to go.

Answer (score 0):

The first patch for Watch Dogs includes a fix that should solve this problem. Excerpt from [patch notes](http://www.incgamers.com/2014/06/watch-dogs-pc-patch-in-the-coming-days):

> Automatically reconstructed corrupted save files which prevented loading to go further than 90%. Some collectibles may remain unrecoverable.

The patch will be available on all platforms. Although it doesn't have a set release date yet, it will be available in the "the coming days".

Answer (score -1):

The best fixes I've found so far are here: http://www.crashwiki.com/top-8-fixes-watch-dogs-pc-blue-screen-crashes-unable-start-dx11-errors-mouse-acceleration-controller-lag-sound-vista-required/

Comment: Can you summarize the linked information here, please?  That way, if the site ever goes down, your answer is still valid.  Plus, it saves people a click.